# Why is githup-pages not loading all my files for my project?

Tags: node.js, github-pages

I've been trying to find a way to host the projects I have been practicing with online but have not come up with a good solution. For this specific project I included node.js so I created a "dist" folder with all the necessary code to create my website. I tried using GitHub and followed the instructions from this link:

https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490

After completing the steps and visiting the site I only see the html text being displayed. No images, JavaScript, or Css. (note my settings are set to source the code from the github-pages subtree using the root folder). See Here:

https://unchich.github.io/Intro-component-with-sign-up-form/

Also here is the link to my GitHub repository:

https://github.com/UnChich/Intro-component-with-sign-up-form

I understand things could of been simple if I didn't go the route of using node.js and using gulp to build my distribution folder but its all for practice and for demo purposes. Id appreciate any guidance or help solving my issue with hosting my site on github-pages. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Request URL for you `js` and `css` file is wrong.
Check in developer tools

```
Request URL: https://unchich.github.io/js/scripts.js
```

You should replace
[Line 34](https://github.com/UnChich/Intro-component-with-sign-up-form/blob/33115a089cac7ca88c456216a77d9c7b7c6662e4/index.html#L34)

```
<script src="/js/script.js" defer></script>
```

with

```
<script src="js/script.js" defer></script>
```

and [Line 24](https://github.com/UnChich/Intro-component-with-sign-up-form/blob/33115a089cac7ca88c456216a77d9c7b7c6662e4/index.html#L24)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
```

with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
```

And similarly for other `js` and `css` files.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my issue for my files. Glad it was a simple coding oversight on my part.